# Why is my tailwindcss margin bottom not getting applied?

Tags: next.js, modal-dialog

Currently I am making a modal for my webapp using Nextjs14, TailwindCSS, I was wondering why my mb-6 is not getting applied between the button and the

tag. Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import CloseButton from "@/app/ui/CloseButton";
import Image from "next/image";
import googleLogo from "@/public/google-logo.svg";
import twitterLogo from "@/public/twitter-logo.svg";
import emailLogo from "@/public/email-logo.svg";
import { notoSans } from "@/app/ui/fonts";
import { LoginOrKickOffModalProps } from "@/app/lib/types";

export default function LoginOrKickOffModal({
  option,
  onClose,
}: LoginOrKickOffModalProps) {
  const handleOverlayClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
  ) => {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex justify-center items-center bg-black bg-opacity-30"
      onClick={handleOverlayClick}
    >
      <div
        className="bg-white w-full h-full md:w-[570px] md:h-[670px] rounded-lg shadow-lg animate-slide-in flex flex-col justify-center items-center p-6 relative"
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        <div className="absolute top-6 right-6">
          <CloseButton onClose={onClose} />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-4">
          <h1 className="text-4xl tracking-tighter font-medium mb-12">
            {option === "login" ? "Welcome back!" : "Let's get started."}
          </h1>
          <button className="w-[300px] h-[48px] mb-2 rounded-3xl border border-black active:scale-95">
            <div className="relative flex justify-center items-center w-full">
              <Image
                src={googleLogo}
                alt="Google Logo"
                className="absolute left-3"
                width={22}
                height={22}
              />
              Continue with Google
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className="w-[300px] h-[48px] mb-2 rounded-3xl border border-black active:scale-95">
            <div className="relative flex justify-center items-center w-full">
              <Image
                src={twitterLogo}
                alt="Twitter Logo"
                className="absolute left-3"
                width={22}
                height={22}
              />
              Continue with Twitter
            </div>
          </button>
          <button className="w-[300px] h-[48px] rounded-3xl border border-black active:scale-95 mb-6">
            <div className="relative flex justify-center items-center w-full">
              <Image
                src={emailLogo}
                alt="Email Logo"
                className="absolute left-3"
                width={22}
                height={22}
              />
              Continue with Email
            </div>
          </button>

          <p>
            Already have an account?{" "}
            <span className="font-bold text-[#27b1c1]">Sign in</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[As you can see, the margin is not showing between the continue with email button and the following text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmLYf.png)

I tried to surround the

tag in a div, and that did not work. I tried using padding for the p-tag, which worked, but I have been using margins throughout and do not want to interrupt that format.